# Haarschnitt Begriffe (Haircut terms)

Tags: vocabulary

How would one say that ones hair needs a trim?

"Mein Haar braucht einen Schnitt?" I think this is "My hair needs a cut."

But how would one say " a trim," as in walking into the Hair Salon and saying: " I just need a trim, please."  "Bitte, ich will nur Abschneiden." perhaps?

Comment: Be careful! *Abschneiden* isn't trimming but trimming to zero (or near zero). Trimming is *kürzen* or *nachschneiden*. And don't use the English *trimming* either, because the hairdresser could understand she should use a *Haartrimmer* (and trim to near zero, of course.)

Comment: Perhaps something with "nachschneiden", but this is not my area of expertise.

Answer (score 6):

"Mein Haar braucht einen Schnitt?", would be understood, but sounds a bit funny. Kind of like a word play that a native would use. Normally one would say something like: "Meine Haare müssen geschnitten werden." or "Ich möchte meine Haare schneiden lassen." However if you enter a *Friseursalon*, this is usually assumed. The main information to transmit is what exactly you want. First of all you would want to pick among: *Schneiden, Waschen, Färben*...., which you can combine with *und* or *nur*. For instance you could say:

> Nur Schneiden bitte.
>
> Waschen und Schneiden bitte

Assuming that with "I just need a trim, please.", you mean that they only need to do a small "refresh", that would be:

> Nachschneiden

Comment: I would also like to suggest "Nur Spitzen schneiden, bitte" - "Only trim the ends, please."